# OSX El Capitan 10.11.3 Bluetooth not available

Tags: bluetooth, osx-elcapitan

I am having some issues to get back to function my bluetooth (OS X El Capitan V.10.11.3, after the update), just presents a message as NOT AVAILABLE. I tried [This solution](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203646) without any response.

Later, I tried to reboot the SMC like the following:

> How to Reset SMC in a MacBook Air, MacBook Pro Retina, or MacBook
>   Pro’s (with non-removable batteries)
>
> Step #1. Turn off your MacBook (any of the above version). Step #2.
>   Attach the power adapter to your Mac. Step #3. Press
>   Control+Shift+Option keys and power button together for some time and
>   then release the keys. Ctrl, Shift, Option, and Power Key Combination
>   Step #4. Start the boot as usual.

From [here](http://www.igeeksblog.com/fix-bluetooth-not-available-error-mac/).

Also not working with my issue.

It's really frustrating, damn macs.

Comment: Which was the previous version of your OSX? Just so I know not to update, in case I can run into the same problem.

Comment: Always El Capitan, I imagine 10.11.2 or 10.11.1. I just bought the macbook on december.

Comment: I would try contacting the apple store, to fix or replace it for free.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem since 2015 usually after waking the computer, Bluetooth would show as unavailable and I have tried just about everything suggested by answers I found online. The only solution I have come across that works 100% for me is by going to `System Preferences` -> `General` -> **unchecking** `Allow Handoff between this Mac and your iCloud devices`

It has been a month of observing this problem that occured daily and never had an issue afterwards. Hope this might help some of you out there.